# Passing a javascript variable to php with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to pass JavaScript file variable to php to open the file in new window, but it seems, it is not working accurately

JavaScript code

```
function Open(){
    var file = prompt("Enter a File name to open with .txt");
    $.get( "php/OpenFile.php",
        file,
        function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
}
```

PHP Code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];

$file2 = file_get_contents($file);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open($file2)</script>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add sanity check to file requested

Comment: This doesn't look secure at all. You shouldn't let a user display any file they want (unless you really don't care)

Comment: What is the output that you get, to `console.log`? What is the expected output?

Comment: I know of the security involved. i am new to these languages and i'm trying to learn them. I won't be using it without out restriction.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Open(){
    var file = prompt("Enter a File name to open with .txt");
    $.get( "php/OpenFile.php",
        {file: file},
        function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
}
```

In your Javascript, you are not sending the file name with an identifier. You can think of the Javascript object `{file: file}` as the html tag `<input name='file' type='text' />`

---

If you are looking to open the file in a new window, no AJAX is needed.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Open()">Open File</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Open() {
    var file = prompt("Enter a File name to open with .txt");
    window.open("php/OpenFile.php?file="+file);
}
```

This may; however, be blocked by popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
function Open(){
    var file = prompt("Enter a File name to open with .txt");
    $.get( "php/OpenFile.php",
        {"file": file}, //    <---------------- Give the variable a name ("file")
        function(result){
            window.open(result); // Open a window with the result
        }
    );
}
```

**php/OpenFile.php**

```
<?php
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    echo file_get_contents($file);
?>
```

---

Another way would be not to use Ajax:

```
function Open(){
    var file = prompt("Enter a File name to open with .txt");
    window.open(file); // Open the file in a window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open new window (without AJAX) by

```
<script>
function openwindow(file_name)
{
window.open("your_script.php?file="+file_name,
    "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=300,height=300");
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:openwindow('test')">open window</a>
```

And **your_script.php**

```
<?php
$file = trim($_GET['file']);
$file = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/",'',$file); 

$full_filename =  'directory/' . $file . '.txt';
if (is_readable($full_filename )) 
  {
  readfile($full_filename);
  }
else die('I can not open file:' . $file);
```

?>

Comment: if i want to open the file as a text file instead, how would i do that?

Comment: in window.open you can set direct path to target file not only to php "reader" ex window.open("directory/" + file_name, "mywindow" .....); If you send file by php you can control access (if you need) and user don't know where is real file location.

Comment: can you also target text file?

Comment: yes you can enter path to any file you want in window.open, If file is readable by your WWW server then will be send to browser. Browser do with this content what can do ;) txt file probably show. In above example : your_script.php file extesion will be add to string in php - this is for security reasons - then only *.txt files from directory/ will be readable other extensions are excluded.